# Background Threads and Tasks

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, apache-kafka, task, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to find the best way to run a Task from a dedicated background thread.

The context of usage is consuming from a Kafka topic and raising an async event handler to handle the ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue> instance.

A Kafka Consumer (the `consumer` instance below) blocks the thread until a message is consumed or the  CancellationToken it is passed has been cancelled.

```
consumeThread = new Thread(Consume)
{
    Name = "Kafka Consumer Thread",
    IsBackground = true,
};
```

This is the implementation of the Consume method I came up with, which is started by the dedicated thread above:

```
private void Consume(object _)
{
    try
    {
        while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            var consumeResultEventArgs = new ConsumeResultReceivedEventArgs<TKey, TValue>(
                consumer, consumeResult, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                if (onConsumeResultReceived is null) continue;

                var handlerInstances = onConsumeResultReceived.GetInvocationList();
                foreach (ConsumeResultReceivedEventHandler<TKey, TValue> handlerInstance in handlerInstances)
                {
                    if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return;                        
                    await handlerInstance(this, consumeResultEventArgs).ConfigureAwait(false);                            
                }

            }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {

    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {

    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        // Aborting a thread is not implemented in .NET Core.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the recommened way to run a Task from a dedicated Thread, so any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you need a dedicated thread at all. The code as it currently stands starts a thread and then that thread blocks for consumption and then raises the event handler on a thread pool thread.

The `_ = Task.Run` idiom is a "fire and forget", which is dangerous in the sense that it will silently swallow any exceptions from your event raising code or event handlers.

I'd recommend replacing `Thread` with `Task.Run`, and just raising the event handlers directly:

```
consumeTask = Task.Run(ConsumeAsync);

private async Task ConsumeAsync()
{
  while (true)
  {
    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    var consumeResultEventArgs = new ConsumeResultReceivedEventArgs<TKey, TValue>(
        consumer, consumeResult, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    if (onConsumeResultReceived is null) continue;

    var handlerInstances = onConsumeResultReceived.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (ConsumeResultReceivedEventHandler<TKey, TValue> handlerInstance in handlerInstances)
    {
      if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return;
      await handlerInstance(this, consumeResultEventArgs).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Steven. I've been thoroughly enjoying your blog. I've always assumed that thread-blocking calls (such as Kafka's client library Consume above) in a task were to be avoided - thus the dedicated thread. The dedicated thread might block, but it wouldn't unduly keep busy a threadpool thread dedicated to running tasks. However I'd gladly use your solution if my concerns are unfounded.

Comment: The thread pool will self-adjust, usually after a couple of seconds. So by using `Task.Run`, you are taking a thread from a thread pool, and it will spin up a new one a few seconds later. This is fine for a very long-lived thread, but you wouldn't want to do this often - e.g., don't use `Task.Run` in ASP.NET where it would run for each request.